# The Lagrangian approach needs more information than the Newtonian approach?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, boundary-conditions

The Newtonian approach:

Given $x(t_0)$, $v(t_0)$ and potential $V(x)$, you solve for $x(t)$.

I've read that the Lagrangian approach replaces the information $v(t_0)$ with the information $x(t_1)$.

I don't see how that's true though. I think the Lagrangian approach would need both $v(t_0)$ and $x(t_1)$.

If you're gonna integrate the kinetic energies along all possible paths from $x(t_0)$ and $x(t_1)$, don't you need the initial kinetic energy? The kinetic energy function along any path would be dependent on the initial KE. Am I wrong?

Comment: Read where? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic I read it on this site. I'll try to get some links. I think the idea was that there's a second degree differential equation. So you need two pieces of information to make the solution unique. The Newtonian approach uses the position and velocity, while the Langranian uses two positions.

Comment: with Lagrangian approach or Newton approach you generate the differential equations  (equations of motions) not the solution of the differential equation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm unsure if I understood your question but perhaps the most simple example clears this. Consider the equation $$\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}=0.$$

The general solution is $x(t)=A+Bt$. Observe that $$x(0)=A,\quad \dot{x}(0)=B.$$

Hence there is a two-parameter family of solutions to the differential equation and we can choose one by specifying $x(0)$ and $\dot{x}(0)$. Still, observe that $$x(0)=A,\quad x(1)=A+B.$$

In that case if I give you $x(0)$ and $x(1)$ you can still get a unique solution out of the family. Indeed suppose you give $x(0)=x_0$ and $x(1)=x_1$ then $A=x_0$ and $B=x_1-x_0$.

In a sense it is just a distinct way of parameterizing your solutions. It doesn't matter if you use Newtonian or Lagrangian formalism, you will end up with second-order differential equations and these have unique solutions when you specify two quantities for each unknown function.